# Tomcat and Jenkins: Unable to create the home directory ‘/opt/tomcat/.jenkins’

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I'm trying to install Jenkins however I think there is an issue with how I've setup Tomcat.

Basically, I followed along an online tutorial to install Tomcat on Ubuntu 16.04:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04

```
sudo groupadd tomcat
sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /opt/tomcat tomcat
```

It also instructed to set ownership and permissions of the tomcat home directory which I've done:

```
sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat
sudo chmod -R g+r conf
sudo chmod g+x conf
sudo chown -R tomcat webapps/ work/ temp/ logs/
```

So I can see the /opt/tomcat directory appears to be set for Tomcat to be able to write:

```
$ ls -la /opt/tomcat
total 156
drwxr-xr-x 9 root   tomcat  4096 Oct  9 17:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root   root    4096 Oct  9 17:41 ..
drwxr-x--- 2 root   tomcat  4096 Oct  9 17:41 bin
-rw-r----- 1 root   tomcat 19318 Sep 16 19:19 BUILDING.txt
drwxr-x--- 2 root   tomcat  4096 Oct  9 18:10 conf
...
```

However, when I try to display the now installed Jenkins in the browser it tells me that there are issues with permissions:

```
Unable to create the home directory ‘/opt/tomcat/.jenkins’. This is most likely a permission problem.

To change the home directory, use JENKINS_HOME environment variable or set the JENKINS_HOME system property. See Container-specific documentation for more details of how to do this.
```

Is there anything obvious that I've missed? If there is anything more I need to post, happy to update here. Should I set tomcat as the owner as well as the group? It will be a production server, so don't want to give more permissions than necessary and it didn't state to do that in the tutorials I've seen.

Comment: _So I can see the /opt/tomcat directory appears to be set for Tomcat to be able to write:_ Look closer, only root can write.  Only owner has write permissions and root is the owner of everything listed.

Comment: The other comments have already covered the permissions issue, but your situation in general seems very strange to me:  You do not need to install Tomcat to run Jenkins (Jenkins embeds its own web server), and Jenkins typically runs as the `jenkins` user, not as `tomcat`.

Answer (score 1):

> So I can see the /opt/tomcat directory appears to be set for Tomcat to be able to write

this is wrong, only **root** can write in the folder, looking at your log.
you should chmod g+w /opt/tomcat

```
drwxr-xr-x 9 root   tomcat  4096 Oct  9 17:41 .

this means: rwx for the owner (root)
            r-x for the group (tomcat) -- only read,no write
            r-x for others
```

regards